# Opening an Existing project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I'm trying to open an existing project in Eclipse but the project is not showing up on the LIST of project. Can anyone help out I've tried on the NET and it seems like i can't find the right solution ?

I tried this : File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code into Workplace > Root to directory . but i can't get my project on the LIST of Project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : File > Import > General > Existing Android Code into Workplace > Select Archive File. It will help, if it's in zip or rar!!!

Else:

File > Import > General > Existing Android Code into Workplace > Root to directory. It will help.!!

Comment: I tried to use your first solution but it gives me an Error :  Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace ,how can i solve it ? and the 2nd one doesn't seems to work at all because its not giving me expected result.

Comment: it means that ur project is not in the desired android format.. where did u get from>

Comment: I downloaded it from Internet but its works fine on my machine at home but here at work its not working.Thanks Exeptional i'll get it to work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is composed of few classes try to create a new project with the same classes of that project and fill them with the original code by copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your project might already be existing in your workspace... Just try File>Open Project....

Else it would be better if you elaborate your question with facts like what is the format of your project and if it's a war file then what version of tomcat you're running...